# Pyspark: Replace all occurrences of a value with null in dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe similar to below. I originally filled all null values with -1 to do my joins in Pyspark.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Number': ['1', '2', '-1', '-1'],
                   'Letter': ['A', '-1', 'B', 'A'],
                   'Value': [30, 30, 30, -1]})


pyspark_df = spark.createDataFrame(df)

+------+------+-----+
|Number|Letter|Value|
+------+------+-----+
|     1|     A|   30|
|     2|    -1|   30|
|    -1|     B|   30|
|    -1|     A|   -1|
+------+------+-----+
```

After processing the dataset, I need to replace all -1 back to null values.

```
+------+------+-----+
|Number|Letter|Value|
+------+------+-----+
|     1|     A|   30|
|     2|  null|   30|
|  null|     B|   30|
|  null|     A| null|
+------+------+-----+
```

What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another way to do this in a less verbose manner is to use **`replace`**.

```
pyspark_df.replace(-1,None).replace('-1',None).show()
```

Comment: @anky same, i tried to pass a dictionary of both like {1:None, '-1':None} cuz to_replace can accept a dictionary but it gave error that mixed data type replacements are not supported so had to do replace twice

Comment: I'd be curious to know how these methods compare against each other in terms of time/efficiency?  @anky Do you have any intuition? Both would seem optimized since you are using pyspark functions. My df is 100 million rows, so I'll give it a test :)

Comment: @sanjayr im curious, let us know which is faster

Comment: It's a bit hard to get apples to apples comparison because I'm sharing a cluster, but it seems that `.replace` is a bit faster. Guessing since we don't use a for loop link in @anky answer

Comment: I see, I think it’s the casting every column to int that’s making it slightly slower as there is no casting in replace

Answer (score 5):

`when+otherwise` shall do the trick:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

pyspark_df.select([F.when(F.col(i).cast("Integer") <0 , None).otherwise(F.col(i)).alias(i)
                  for i in df.columns]).show()
```

---

```
+------+------+-----+
|Number|Letter|Value|
+------+------+-----+
|     1|     A|   30|
|     2|  null|   30|
|  null|     B|   30|
|  null|     A| null|
+------+------+-----+
```

Answer (score 3):

You can scan all columns and replace `-1`'s with None:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

for x in pyspark_df.columns:
    pyspark_df = pyspark_df.withColumn(x, F.when(F.col(x)==-1, F.lit(None)).otherwise(F.col(x)))

pyspark_df.show()
```

Output:

```
+------+------+-----+
|Number|Letter|Value|
+------+------+-----+
|     1|     A|   30|
|     2|  null|   30|
|  null|     B|   30|
|  null|     A| null|
+------+------+-----+
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **`reduce`** to apply **`when+otherwise`** on all columns on dataframe.

```
df.show()
#+------+------+-----+
#|Number|Letter|Value|
#+------+------+-----+
#|     1|     A|   30|
#|     2|    -1|   30|
#|    -1|     B|   30|
#+------+------+-----+
from functools import reduce

(reduce(lambda new_df, col_name: new_df.withColumn(col_name, when(col(col_name)== '-1',lit(None)).otherwise(col(col_name))),df.columns,df)).show()
#+------+------+-----+
#|Number|Letter|Value|
#+------+------+-----+
#|     1|     A|   30|
#|     2|  null|   30|
#|  null|     B|   30|
#+------+------+-----+
```